# Rendez-vous with your eccentric uncle

Tags: cipher, pattern, steganography

Your eccentric uncle is a world-renowned cryptologist and he sees in you a high potential to follow in his footsteps. You are of course very flattered and can't wait to get going with the special training program he has set up for you. Your training will commence tomorrow at a rendez-vous point that your uncle has communicated to you by means of an encrypted message. To prove that you are worthy, decrypt the message and find out where the rendez-vous will take place!

The message reads:

> [image: Message]

*Note: The puzzle contains multiple layers and is best solved one step at a time. Only the message itself is needed to solve this puzzle, all the rest is just flavour text.*

Since it seems to be unclear how to deal with the different layers, I will add a little hint in the form of an example here:

> Say the message were: "hI, th***i***s Is ***a*** HiN***T*** Me***S***sAge", then this can be seen as a combination of two layers. In one layer some characters have been capitalized: "hI, this Is a HiNT MeSsAge" and in another layer some letters where made bold and italicized (both were done at the same time, just to make the letters jump out a little more): "hi, th***i***s is ***a*** hin***t*** me***s***sage".
> When working on solving one layer, you can (and should) ignore all other layers. The solution will then provide a clue for the next layer. The layers must be solved in a specific order, though.

Hint for the first layer:

> For the first layer the exact characters are not important, just the pattern of highlighted vs. non-highlighted characters. The solution is 43 characters long.

Hint 2:

> For the first layer should be read as a binary string.

Comment: Are the colors used for grouping or just for distraction? You can chose not to answer :)

Comment: None of the text formatting is there just for distraction ;)

Comment: @levieux do we need to go piece by piece or layer by layer?

Comment: Is the message important? Or just the formatting in the text?

Comment: Layer by layer is the way to go. Also, when you're working on a certain layer you can ignore the other layers.

Comment: @Sid: the message itself is not important, except for one line, which may come in handy later.

Comment: @Levieux - I assume, the added hint says, a clue can be combination of any pattern i.e. you are combining bold letters(lower or upper case doesn't matter) in the same way, we might need to try various patters for a single line. This might become too hectic to brute force all the possibilities. e.g. I can apply 8 possibilities for line one and I do not have any clue what to do with the extracted letters as they are just gibberish. Can't you add the length of the words or something like a synonym which can be taken out of each line? It would atleast give solvers a bit of clue about the o/p.

Comment: @Techidiot: I'll try to clarify the hint a little bit more in a minute. Also, I can add that for the first part the exact characters are not important, only the pattern is. The solution to this part is another "message", 43 characters long.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Final Answer

Rendez-vous will take place at -

> **CENTRAL PARK**

Taking the clue from the Hint "For the first layer should be read as a binary string."

> If the first layer mean - uppercase treated as 1's and lower case as
>  0's we get - 215 characters turned into binary as -
>  **101001001001001100000000001000110010010101110000010000**
>  **00010100001101000000001011010011011101001000000010100001001110110000**
>  **10100000110010000110111011100000001001100100111101110010010001100000**
>  **1001110100110010110000101**

Another hint says the first layer gives 43 characters hence-

> We need to split the 215 binary into group of 5 to get 43 characters.

So..

> Grouping them into 5-bits and checking the corresponding letter we get
>  10100 = 20 =  **T**
>  10010 = 18 =  **R**
>  01001 = 9 =   **I**
>  ....
>  We get **"TRIP HYENA EAT KIWI EAGLE YAWN IRONIC STYLE"** (Treating 00000 as space")

So...

> Taking first letters we get - > **THE KEY IS** and Thanks to Ankoganit for figuring out the key. which are last letters **PATIENCE**

Knowing this(Thanks to @Sconibulus, @Gareth) -

> PATIENCE is an 8 letter word. So, checking the pattern with bold characters we get **aeybssdvxgabsstvdtmes** Applying Vigenère cipher with **PATIENCE** as key we get **LeftOFBrighTOfrrotTwo** which means **Left OF B(blue) righT  Of r(red) rot-Two(rot-2)**

Hence,

> Taking the letter's left of Blue and right of Red colored ones, we get - **aclrpyjnypi** and applying **rot-2** gives **centralpark**

So the rendez-vous will take place at -

> **Central Park**

All thanks to @Gareth, @dcfyj, @Ankoganit and @Sconibulus. Would have costed a lot of brainstorming solving this one.

With that done, I would say, the solution will be too difficult without hints as the puzzle doesn't speak of what to apply where.

Comment: This is indeed the right track, but you're not taking grouping by the correct number of characters yet... Also, read the whole message, not line by line. The lines have no significance

Comment: RSA is by no means the solution of the first part. Like I said, you're not grouping by the correct number of characters, so these letters are incorrect. But you are on the right track, just don't think ASCII..

Comment: @Levieux-How can we know how to form the groupings and how many characters in each group? There are so many combinations possible :-/ As said, it will be almost impossible to solve it if we are going to have many steps like this one.

Comment: I added as a hint that the solution to part 1 would contain 43 characters, so that should get you going ;)

Comment: @Levieux - 43 characters in binary will require 43*8=344 characters? But I do not think the message has 344 characters. How is that possible? :-/

Comment: I have no clue how to form 344 long binary string out of the message. :-/

Comment: Like I said, don't focus on groupings of 8 characters (a.k.a. ASCII). There are other ways to encode characters in binary. If I'm not mistaken the message contains exactly 215 letters...

Comment: Well done, and thanks for your feedback! For future puzzles I'll add a few more hints to nudge you in the right direction. My desire not to make this puzzle too easy to solve has probably resulted in it becoming too difficult.

Answer (score 1):

**Partial Answer**

> The red-coloured words spell out to be "hidtta"
> The Bold-Capital Letters spell out to be "AYSSDBM"
> The Bold-Small-letters spell out to be "eybvxgsvdt"
> The blue-lettered words spell out to be "oatts"

Now each of these words seem to be somehow encoded.

> With a Brief trip to quipqiup, I see that the most sensible things that came out to be was:
>  hiddta-Blessi (Must be blessings)
>  ayssdbm-But ther (Must be "but there")
>  eybvxgsvdt-Under the co
>  oatts-get to

I don't see an exact place. Maybe, my plaintext words are wrong, but this is the best I got.

Comment: No grouping for Normal Capital Letters which are "TMAYOTTWRISADHEDNORTVENOMPRBNEAOEANUNTRAWTTEYRSFLEEYOUEAEVESANTLSELLED" ? :)

Comment: @Techidiot Nothing great coming out of that...

Comment: You're not on the right track yet. Be sure to take things one step at a time.